# How can I embed a watermark or a text at a VIMEO video

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video

We are an NGO and we are producing few video contents periodically which we use to transmit through Vimeo. I would like to add our information into the video throughout when one plays at full screen.

I couldn’t find any API where I can run a message somewhere at the bottom or at the top or anywhere on the play screen area and that works at the fullscreen view.

I have the premium subscriptions

Thanks
Phil

Comment: is there any reason you're not burning it into the video so it's always there? captions (for instance) can be turned on/off by the user so no guarantee it will be seen? you can use something like ffmpeg to burn text in (`drawtext`) but might be easier to use editing software if you want animation etc

Comment: What I am looking is to be able to identify the video that is originally generated through our website/player. Also our videos are generated instantly without using any third party software so i am looking for a solution that can be done using embedded at video player.

Comment: afaik Vimeo doesn't let you do this, but you could use something like the plyr.io player and force captions on (but disable the button so uses don't turn them off)